# Input string was not in a correct format in grid view RowDataBound?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is HTML dropdown list.

On edit button doesn't bind exact value of label from Item template field

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcountry" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblcountry" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("cnname") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlstate_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblstate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("sname") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcity" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblcity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("cname") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And this is the controllers code:

```
    protected void gvcustomgrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                //Find the blood group DropDownList in the Row
                DropDownList ddlbloodgroup = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlbg") as DropDownList);
                ddlbloodgroup.DataSource = ttdal.getbloodgroup();
                ddlbloodgroup.DataTextField = "bg_name";
                ddlbloodgroup.DataValueField = "bg_id";
                ddlbloodgroup.DataBind();
                ddlbloodgroup.SelectedValue = gvcustomgrid.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

                //Find the country DropDownList in the Row
                DropDownList ddlcountry = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlcountry") as DropDownList);
                ddlcountry.DataSource = ttdal.getcountry();
                ddlcountry.DataTextField = "cnname";
                ddlcountry.DataValueField = "cnid";
                ddlcountry.DataBind();
                ddlcountry.SelectedValue = gvcustomgrid.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

                //Find the state DropDownList in the Row
                DropDownList ddlstate = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlstate") as DropDownList);
                ddlstate.DataSource = ttdal.getstate(Convert.ToInt32(ddlcountry.SelectedValue));
                ddlstate.DataTextField = "sname";
                ddlstate.DataValueField = "sid";
                ddlstate.DataBind();
                ddlstate.SelectedValue = gvcustomgrid.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

                //Find the city DropDownList in the Row
                DropDownList ddlcity = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlcity") as DropDownList);
                ddlcity.DataSource = ttdal.getcity(Convert.ToInt32(ddlstate.SelectedValue));
                ddlcity.DataTextField = "cname";
                ddlcity.DataValueField = "cid";
                ddlcity.DataBind();
                ddlcity.SelectedValue = gvcustomgrid.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            }




        }
    }

    protected void ddlcountry_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Find the state DropDownList in the Row
        DropDownList ddlcountry = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddlcountry.NamingContainer;
        if (row != null)
        {
            if ((row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                DropDownList ddlstate = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlstate");

                ddlstate.DataSource = ttdal.getstate(Convert.ToInt32(ddlcountry.SelectedValue));
                ddlstate.DataValueField = "sid";
                ddlstate.DataTextField = "sname";
                ddlstate.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void ddlstate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Find the city DropDownList in the Row
        DropDownList ddlstate = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddlstate.NamingContainer;
        if (row != null)
        {
            if ((row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                DropDownList ddlcity = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlcity");

                ddlcity.DataSource = ttdal.getcity(Convert.ToInt32(ddlstate.SelectedValue));
                ddlcity.DataValueField = "cid";
                ddlcity.DataTextField = "cname";
                ddlcity.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

What should I do to get the correct format in grid view RowDataBound?

Comment: You should start by checking the values of `ddlcountry.SelectedValue` and `ddlstate.SelectedValue`. Chances are one or both contain a value that cannot be converted to an `int`.

Comment: yes but i'm having problem in converion using findcontrol("").to string();

Comment: can you please change it for me??

Comment: "FindControl to string" that does not make sense. Start by setting breakpoints and break it down step by step. Start with 1 DropDownList. And if that one works add the second etc.

Comment: There is no code containing FindControl.ToString. Which line of code is creating problem for you? Did you debug the code and check what value is set to ddlbloodgroup.SelectedValue ? What is the value set to gridview.DataKeys property.

Comment: @VishalParekh, i've seen the mail. The problem probably lies in the fact that when you bind data to a DropDownList the SelectedValue gets reset. So `ddlcountry.SelectedValue` always has the first item selected because you (re)bind data a few lines before. (ps pelase remove the comment with my email, it's a public site)